# Does Dimensional Vortex's initial attack roll carying over

Tags: dnd-4e

Let's say an enemy would hit an ally with an attack roll of 20, And a swordmage uses Dimensional Vortex to relocate him and make the target use it's attack on a different target. Will the initial attack roll of 20 carry over to the new target or does the enemy make a new roll for that attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Arcane Power, p53:

> **Trigger:** An enemy hits an ally with a melee attack.
>   ...
>   **Hit:** You teleport the target 5 squares. The target then
>   makes its melee attack against a creature you choose. If
>   no creatures are within range of the target, the attack is
>   expended.

It's certainly ambiguously phrased, but I think the key here is actually the trigger. Dimensional Vortex is triggered by the attack *hitting* an ally, so the attack roll is already established. Therefore, when you change the target of the attack with Dimensional Vortex, the enemy's attack roll doesn't change, because you're already *past* the point of rolling the attack and have moved on to determining the effects of the attack.

Comment: Especially since the text says "The target then makes its melee attack" and not "melee attack roll".

Comment: The answer is wrong, see Rules Compendium page 214. "Making an attack" contains making an attack ROLL.

Answer (score 1):

The target makes a new attack roll.

> Hit: You teleport the target 5 squares. The **target** then **makes its melee attack** against a creature you choose. If no creatures are within range of the target, the attack is expended.

Making a melee attack involves making an attack roll unless otherwise noted. Compare to the wording of Guardian's Counter:

> Effect: You and the ally shift up to 2 squares as a free action, swapping positions. You become the target of the triggering attack, in place of the ally. After the **attack is resolved**, you can make a basic attack against the attacker.

Also it is worth noting that the target will always have someone to attack after the teleport, itself.